# html2Image & html2Canvas cuts off div that is in full view

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert a div that is in full view of the viewport to an image. I've tried both html2Canvas and html2Image which are both bearing the same result. I'm trying to nail down a high quality image - but when setting the relevant properties the image gets cut off. Without these properties it super blurry and not suitable for the next steps in the project. Has anyone had any experience with creating high quality images which have then been cut off (and of course got a solution)?

html2Canvas Code:

```
 const downloadImage = () => {
    const capture = document.querySelector('.test-download-123');
    if (capture) {
      html2canvas(capture, {
        letterRendering: 1,
        allowTaint: true,
        logging: true,
        useCORS: true,
        quality: 5,
        scale: 3,
      }).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
        console.log(imgData)
      });
    }
  };
```

Result:

[image: Result]